# Laravel deprecated beforeFilter

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Not to repeat the search for the user I have the following code , but laravel 5.1 **beforeFilter is deprecated**. how to replace it.

The function find is applied only to  edit, update and destroy methods

```
class UserController extends Controller {

private $user;

public function __construct(){

    $this->beforeFilter('@find',['only' => ['edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);

}

public function find(Route $route){
    $this->user = User::find($route->getParameter('user'));
}

...


public function edit()
{
    return view('usuario.edit', ['user' => $this->user]);
}

public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request)
{
    $this->user->fill($request->all());
    $this->user->save();
    Session::flash('message', 'Ok update');
    return Redirect::to('/user');
}


public function destroy()
{
    $this->user->delete();
    Session::flash('message', 'delete ok');
    return Redirect::to('/user');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`beforeFilter()` (well, all filters), have been replaced with middleware. Overall, its a new application layer, and you should probably [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware) on it to address your particular use case, but the syntax and functionality is quite similar:

```
// Before
$this->beforeFilter('filtername', [...options...]);
// After
$this->middleware('middlewarename', [...options...]);
```

Comment: But my function find() is on my controller

Comment: You don't *have* to use middleware, you could just call your method from the constructor $this->find(...)